# Rewriting the admin sales report form

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

In my config file I can easily override the sales -> order grid with my own doing this

```
<blocks>
  <adminhtml>
    <rewrite>
      <sales_order_grid>Mine here</sales_order_grid>
    </rewrite>
  </adminhtml>
</blocks>
```

But I cannot seem to do the same for the report_filter_form which is on the Reports->Sales->Order menu item. If I replace the above rewrite content with

```
<report_filter_form>mine here</report_filter_form>
```

Is this one a special case or something. I've cleared my cache and have no luck. The block is loaded in the controller by doing a ->getBlock('grid.filter.form') then feeding it into a initReportAction and finally rendering the layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking in the layout files I see this:

```
<block type="sales/adminhtml_report_filter_form_order" name="grid.filter.form">
```

So the block that needs overwriting is `sales/adminhtml_report_filter_form_order`,

```
<blocks>
  <sales>
    <rewrite>
      <adminhtml_report_filter_form_order>Mine here</adminhtml_report_filter_form_order>
    </rewrite>
  </sales>
</blocks>
```

Comment: Thanks, I now understand how this was determined but I'm not having as much luck tracing the grid that is used and loaded by getBlock('report_sales_sales.grid'). Any help on that one? I tried search the entire code base for the block name but can't find it.

Comment: Grids are a special case. The "grid container" is usually defined in layout as normal, it has a `$_controller` member variable (in this case `"report_sales_sales"`) that is used to create the grid block automatically. In this case the container is "adminhtml/report_sales_sales" and so the grid is "adminhtml/report_sales_sales_grid".

Comment: As a more generic way of finding classes there is a way of using [block hints in admin](http://classyllama.com/magento/enable-templateblock-hints-in-admin-panel/).